# Cannot start an example build

Tags: openshift-origin, okd

I installed okd 3.11 in single master multiple nodes via the openshift ansible playbooks. When I try the nginx quick start. I get the the follow error when I asks the events of the pod.

*Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  23m                kubelet,  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to set up sandbox container "3d57f7bf012f8737e202ac2db7291b58a3d5fde376ff431395584c165928d475" network for pod "nginx-example-1-build": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-example-1-build_geoffrey-samper" network: error getting ClusterInformation: Get https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default: dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: i/o timeout, failed to clean up sandbox container "3d57f7bf012f8737e202ac2db7291b58a3d5fde376ff431395584c165928d475" network for pod "nginx-example-1-build": NetworkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod "nginx-example-1-build_geoffrey-samper" network: error getting ClusterInformation: Get https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default: dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: i/o timeout*

When I run `oc status` but I can't find any pod with 10.* ip range

In project default on server https://p04:8443

https://docker-registry-default (passthrough) (svc/docker-registry)
dc/docker-registry deploys docker.io/openshift/origin-docker-registry:v3.11
deployment #1 deployed about an hour ago - 1 pod

svc/kubernetes - xxx ports 443->8443, 53->8053, 53->8053

https://registry-console-default (passthrough) (svc/registry-console)
dc/registry-console deploys docker.io/cockpit/kubernetes:latest
deployment #1 deployed about an hour ago - 1 pod

svc/router - xxx ports 80, 443, 1936
dc/router deploys docker.io/openshift/origin-haproxy-router:v3.11
deployment #1 deployed about an hour ago - 1 pod

Does anyone know how to resolve this or where to begin.

Comment: Found the issue there was an old version installed of rancher kubernetes. and Rancher uses 10.43.0. ip range. After cleanup it worked